# Will god get angry if I start worshiping another god?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, moksha, life, desire

I was really inspired by Krishna, The Supreme Lord... After reading Gita. I became his devotee (not pure one), before reading Gita I was still his devotee... Whenever I used to think of him... I used get extreme energy that motivates me so much... But when I read Gita it felt like all I did before was wrong... Now everything I do feels like I am doing wrong... I have become so judgemental... Before reading Gita , I always believed that he is with me but after reading it... It feels like I am becoming sad everyday... I don't know what to do. I am thinking of Becoming Devotee of another lord. Will god get angry? I don't know what is wrong with me. Anyone please give me suggestions... and yes, I am not after moksha, it's not the best for me... I am in need to fulfill my material desires..

Comment: Please read this  book of 140 pages IN FULL before asking further questions as you seem puzzled : https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.128125

Comment: @commonman Sir. I am 16 years old. Should I get into this later on in my life??

Comment: Staying in touch with 5 elements of naturr is spirituality at basics.  So for now just participate in poojas which ur family does be good boy and visit nearby temples regularly!  Enof for now!

Comment: @Kartik Relax, I believe you are hastening things up, you should give it some time to sink in, Simply reading Gita doesn't make one understand it, it takes a lot of time to understand its concepts, try reading other texts too or re-read it.

Comment: To my knowledge each God is supreme devotee of other god. It is a cycle. So no one gets offended.

Comment: *I am in need to fulfill my material desires.* -- material desires is that which will make you sad in your life. The formula of happiness is to go beyond the material desires, to make Lord Krishna the object of your desire, that is the path of happiness.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question is NO he won't get angry.

As far as I remember Krishna himself mentioned that, he resides in all and all resides in him (e.g. Vishwa-Rup).
He also said that if you are worshiping any god, he will come to you in that form as all others are his forms only. So worshiping any one of them will finally lead you to him. (No problem there). But worshipping Krishna is considered best, as he is the supreme god.

Apart from that, I don't remember any text where it is mentioned that one God may get angry upon worshiping others. (I think this concept is prominent in Greek gods, not in Hindus).